# Access denied on Documents\My Pictures\ during 7-zip

Tags: windows, windows-7, 7-zip

I started a long-running archive creation on 7-zip via its command line interface. The items to zip included my Documents folder. Soon after I started it, I noticed several messages from 7-zip like this one:

```
WARNING: Access is denied.
C:\Users\Me\Documents\My Pictures\
```

I stopped the archiving figuring I needed to fix this so my items in Pictures could be included, but that was partly because I didn't notice at first that the "My Pictures" mentioned was not the normal one seen in Users\Me directory but was in the Documents directory.  With Windows Explorer I looked, but didn't see it in My Documents (aka Documents), but then checked for a hidden file by altering the Folder Options to show hidden files.  Sure enough it showed up, but clicking on that "My Pictures" gave me "Access denied".

What's going on here?

Comment: Did you zip the actual default folders, or did you also include the default, backwards compatible personal default folders with shortcut arrows on them? ••• Moreover, why are you performing this route instead of another... because I am absolutely not aware of your "end-goal". Is this a preferential endeavor? ••• Otherwise, kind regards to you and yours

Comment: @ITCornMaze, I included "C:\Users\Me\Documents\" in the list of directories to include.  I  never mentioned "My Pictures", if that's what you are referring to.  My end goal is to have all the the folders and files of \Documents included in the  .7z output archive (less certain sub folders specified in the "NOT" list) Why should I take "another route"?  I have no idea what you mean by "preferential endeavor", so can't say if it is one.

Answer (score 2):

That hidden "My Pictures" folder, along with similar ones named "My Music" and "My Videos", turns out to be a bit of kludgery Microsoft put into NTFS to make NT-based versions of Windows backwards compatible with older programs.  This "My Pictures" thing isn't really a folder but a type of soft link called a "[junction point](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=NTFS_junction_point)". These junction points can't be treated like a folder/directory and be viewed or scanned for contents, but apparently can only used with certain interfaces embedded in path strings like "My Pictures\Album3" used when the current directory is Documents.

7-zip was scanning for items in the Documents folder when it found "My Pictures" item and treated it like a directory and tried to scan it for items, which caused the access denial and the warning to be output.  Apparently the 7-zip code does not understand junction points, as if it did it could have not emitted a warning.  The access denial should have no consequence for the archive operation as 7-zip has no need to use these funny junction point names.

Bottom line: the access warnings on the names like "C:\Users\username\Documents\My Videos" shouldn't be there, and can be safely ignored.

Comment: In W11, empty and inaccessible "my music" "my pictures" "my videos" popped up at some stage in `C:\Users\username`, so deleted them through explorer. Surprise. There are always "Music" "Pictures" "Videos" folders, each containing at least desktop.ini.